# Log level for a business validation error

Tags: java, python-3.x, logging, log4j, log-level

If I have a validation rule that prevents duplicate put requests on an entity , should I log this situation as a error or info in my logs? If I see a error connecting to DB or error calling an external api , I log these as errors. However I want to understand what is the best practice for logging a business error returned by an external api or validation error caught by my service.

Comment: I think the clue is in your text, you keep referring to them as `validation error` and `business error` so if you are calling/referring to them as errors then it seems appropriate to log them as errors.